# I2C - switch scl line

Tags: i2c

I have two identical I2C devices that I need to use with a single MCU (arduino nano). I have read here on EE that an I2C multiplexer can be used to switch between multiple I2C buses. But I find them too expensive. A single pca9540 multiplexer costs at least $5, which is too much. (A complete 40pin pic MCU would costs less...) My idea is to use a digital output pin of the mcu to switch between two different scl lines. Would that work? Is it possible to do it with a few transistors? (2n2222 or BC547 etc.) That would keep costs down.

Comment: You could try using a CD4066 analog switch -- they're about 40¢.

Comment: Good idea, but at 5V it has about 1Kohm on-state resistance. Isn't it a problem for the I2C devices to have an 1K series resistor on the line?

Comment: Yes -- if you had a 1k pull-up and a 1k series resistance, when pulling down on the line, you'd end up just sitting at 0.5Vcc instead of a logic low.

Comment: @nagylzs I didn't realize the 4066 had such a high on-resistance.  The [TS5A4624](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a4624.pdf) SPDT switch has an on resistance of 1Ω and costs 59¢ at Digi-Key.  It only comes in a SMT package (SC-70), but it's easy enough to solder.

Comment: Why don't you use a software I2C driver on a second I2C bus?

Comment: can't set them to different I2C addresses by jumpers?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to switch both signals. Just switch the data would be safest, I think. But then you need bidirectional buffers. If you switch the clock, well, the clock is never driven by the slave, so you can just use open collector logic. And if you want, yes you can do it with transistors. It is easier if you can supply separate enables for each transistor. Can you? I mean, can you spare two IO pins for this?

Comment: TCA9543A a 2 channel i2c bus switch is 1.59 in single quantities on Digikey. 55 cents at 1ku. You just chose an expensive part to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the transistor solution. You need to make sure SEL_1 and SEL_2 are not high at the same time. You need to make sure that one of them is high all the time (because the pullups are on the other side of the FET). If you are not confident of managing that in software, maybe use an inverter. The input to the inverter will be a GPIO, and will also be SEL_1. The output of the inverter will be SEL_2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgivPl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I2C_DA is the I2C data line from the processor. SEL_1 is a GPIO. When high, it selects slave 1. This means that slave 1 will be able to see data sent by the bus master. When SEL_1 is low, slave 1 will only see the data line being high, so it will never respond.

SEL2 is a different GPIO. When SEL_2 is high, it selects slave 2. You should avoid having them both be high. It will not create contention (open collector data line) but if you send out a read on the slave address, and both selects are high, you will get the type of bus collision you are trying to avoid. And you might not realize it right away. The data would not appear obviously corrupted.

Comment: The body diodes of those MOSFETs will allow voltage to leak across them even when off -- I really hate CircuitLab's transistor symbol. Even if both are off, you'll get the voltage on I2C_DA -0.7V on the slaves, if for some reason the slave is driving low.

Comment: Hey, @KrunalDesai, that is not a mistake. I did it that way on purpose. Those are NMOS. The drain is connected to the slaves. When the FET's are off, the drains will be high (pulled up by the resistor). If the select lines are used correctly, the slaves will never drive the data line when they are not supposed to. But you are right that they cannot prevent the slave from driving the line low, even when they are off.

Comment: The idea is to set the select lines correctly before you query the device. Since the de-selected device does not see data toggling, it will never respond. Only the selected device will respond.

Comment: Would this also work with 2n7000 mosfets? They are available in TO92 package and I can buy 100pcs for less than $4.

Comment: I'm accepting this solution because it is cheaper, but the other one is a good one too.

Comment: The threshold voltage on the 2N7000 is a bit higher. It would be better to use the BSS138. If your IO voltage is 5V, the 2N7000 might work, though.

Comment: Yes, arduino nano has 5V io pins. Thresold V_GS is max. 3V for 2N7000, seems to be good. Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick update: 2n7000 is ancient. Ao3400 has Vgs threshold 1V and rdson=25 mOhm, sot-23 and dirt cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in a single-master situation, using an IC like the [TS12A12511](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts12a12511.pdf), a single SPDT switch would let you do this with one extra I/O pin:

[image: TS12A12511 Sample]

MCU_GPIO controls which one you talk too -- I assume you don't need a 'float / no-connect mode'. The on-state resistance of this switch is ~5 ohms, which is virtually nothing for I2C. I assume that your I2C bus runs at the MCU voltage, so you should tie that to the V+ pin on the switch. The part can slew rail-to-rail, so there should be no problems there.

I would then also place my I2C pull-up resistors on both SLAVE_0_SCL and SLAVE_1_SCL -- this prevents floating input pins at the slaves which can cause undesired behavior, which would be the case if you left the SCL pull-up on the 'MCU_SCL' side of the switch.

I don't know what your quantities are, but this drops to about $1 at 100 pieces.

Comment: Whoops, that's a 10-pin DFN. Hold on, I'll change it to a more suitable part -- DONE.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities worth considering:

- Some I2C peripherals have an address select input which could be wired differently on the two devices
- Others have an interface enable pin, especially those with dual-mode SPI/I2C interfaces, this can be used as a sort of "chip select"
- You could bit-bang a second I2C bus
- Some MCUs (though not your ATmega328) can have the hardware I2C engine assigned to a variety of I/O pins, though dynamically switching this can present some software state challenges